# can't connect please help

Tags: configuration, network-configuration

I'm using my cellphones hotspot. I always use it with tor. I changed my clock ahead 2 hours after the last time I connected. I got a error log that said my clock was wrong changed that now I get this one. I have no idea what to do someone please help me figure this out.

```
6/17/2015 8:57:01 AM.403 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/17/2015 8:57:01 AM.403 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
6/17/2015 8:57:01 AM.798 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
6/17/2015 8:58:11 AM.880 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/17/2015 8:58:11 AM.890 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
6/17/2015 8:58:11 AM.890 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/17/2015 8:58:11 AM.890 [WARN] connection_connect_sockaddr(): Bug: Tried to open a socket with DisableNetwork set. 
6/17/2015 8:58:11 AM.890 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH ]; NOROUTE; count 1; recommendation warn; host 44BEEA03A5338D7308D06DA3D56F1F2F2F9FBFC2 at 88.198.227.74:22) 
6/17/2015 8:58:13 AM.626 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: DisableNetwork means that it doesn't have network connectivity. Make sure you can get online and that nothing is blocking it.

Answer (score 2):

The important bit of information from the logs is `Network is unreachable [WSAENETUNREACH ]; NOROUTE`. (Second line from the bottom.)

A couple of ideas:

1. Check you can connect to the internet normally (i.e. without using Tor).
2. If you're using your cellphone as a hotspot, is your phone connecting to the internet via 3G/4G, or via WiFi? If via WiFi (perhaps in a cafe, or somewhere else where you don't normally use the internet), you might be trying to connect to the internet via an ISP that blocks Tor, in which case you would need to use a Tor bridge.

I'd check #1 first...